# Implementing SQLite into Android App

Tags: java, android, sql

I am new to Android and I am making a simple Log in/Register app. At the moment my problem is that the SQLite database create is not executing meaning that it wont make my table. I have made:

Register.java

```
public class Register extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText insertUsername, insertName, insertPassword, insertFinal;
    Button create;
    LoginDBAdapter loginHandler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_register);

        insertUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertUsername);
        insertName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertName);
        insertPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertPassword);
        insertFinal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertFinal);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();

        close();
    }

    private void close() {
        loginHandler.close();
    }

    private void open() {
        loginHandler = new LoginDBAdapter(this);
        loginHandler.open();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String username = insertUsername.getText().toString();
        String name = insertName.getText().toString();
        String password = insertPassword.getText().toString();
        String confirm = insertFinal.getText().toString();

        //Validation for the fields
        // check if any of the fields are vaccant
        if (username.equals("") || password.equals("") || confirm.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        // check if both password matches
        if (!password.equals(confirm)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        } else {
            // Save the Data in Database

            loginHandler.register(username, name, password);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

LoginAdapter.

```
public class LoginDBAdapter {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DataBaseHelper myHelp;

    // Labels table name
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Users";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";

    // Labels Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_Username = "Username";
    public static final String KEY_name = "Name";
    public static final String KEY_password = "Password";

    // property help us to keep data
    public int User_id;
    public String Username;
    public String Name;
    public String Password;

    public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+ TABLE_NAME+
        "("  + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement ,"
        + KEY_Username + "Username text not null, "
        + KEY_name + "Name text not null, "
        + KEY_password +"Password text not null);";

    private final Context context;
    public LoginDBAdapter(Context data) {
        this.context = data;
        myHelp = new DataBaseHelper(context);
    }

    public LoginDBAdapter open(){
        db = myHelp.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        myHelp.close();
    }

    public long register(String username, String name, String password){

        ContentValues newUser = new ContentValues();

        newUser.put(KEY_Username, username);
        newUser.put(KEY_name, name);
        newUser.put(KEY_password, password);

        //Inserting put information into a new row into Users table
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, newUser);
    }

    public String authLogin(String username) {
        Cursor cursor = db.query("Users", null, " Username= ?", new String[]{username}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
            cursor.close();
            return "Username does not exist";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Password"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;
    }

    private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final int version = 1;
        public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, version);
        }

        //This is called if no database exists and DataBaseHelper will create a new one

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME+
                "("  + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                + KEY_Username + "Username text not null, "
                + KEY_name + "Name text not null, "
                + KEY_password +"Password text not null)");
        }

        // Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
        // of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase create_db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            // Log the version upgrade.
            Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            //Destroy all data
            create_db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + "TEMPLATE");
            // Create a new one.
            onCreate(create_db);
        }

    }

}
```

What have I done wrong? I had the project at one point pass the username, name and password passed to register but could not insert into table Users because it doesnt exist. I ran it through Android Device Monitor

No table: Users

Comment: Please don't edit your question to remove the text. People spent their valuable time trying to help you. Removing the question makes that a waste of their time. If one of the answers helped you, you should accept it as the answer to your problem. If you solved the problem on your own, you could add your own answer explaining the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your SQL statement.

```
+ KEY_Username + "Username text not null, "
```

This will render as

```
"UsernameUsername text not null, "
```

So you should probably change it to:

```
+ KEY_Username + " text not null, "
```

The same mistake is in other lines as well.

Comment: Thanks, I have made a change, could you see any other error that is preventing me to insert a row or create the table? Also in teh register java file loginhandler is apparently a null pointer I dont know why I have made instances of the adapter

Comment: Post your logcat stacktrace and point out the relevant row numbers in your code.

Comment: E/SQLiteLog(9249): (1) table Users has no column named Name
E/SQLiteDatabase(9249): Error inserting Name=nane Password=pass Username=username
E/SQLiteDatabase(9249): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Users has no column named Name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Users(Name,Password,Username) VALUES (?,?,?)


Logcat doesnt display but I checked Android Device Monitor. It doesnt create the database

Comment: Assuming you're using Eclipse with ADT: Window -> Show view -> Other > Android -> LogCat

Comment: The error makes a lot of sense (no such column Name), since you're creating the column NameName instead of Name

Comment: I am using Android Studio and I have already changed my query string already and that gave me the error shown through android device monitor

Comment: So if the error changed, that means that my answer is correct. You now encounter a different problem, which you should probably put into a new question and accept this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are never calling this method

```
private void open() {
    loginHandler = new LoginDBAdapter(this);
    loginHandler.open();
}
```

from the Register class.
I suggest to change the onCreate method as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_register);

    insertUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertUsername);
    insertName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertName);
    insertPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertPassword);
    insertFinal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertFinal);

    open();
}
```

Comment: thanks I added instances earlier but forgot to open.

Answer (score 0):

> use this code.it will help you out to create a table in sqlite as well as you can store the Registeration details too

**Register.java**

```
public class Register extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText insertUsername, insertName, insertPassword, insertFinal;
Button create;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_register);

    insertUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertUsername);
    insertName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertName);
    insertPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertPassword);
    insertFinal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.insertFinal);
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    String username = insertUsername.getText().toString();
    String name = insertName.getText().toString();
    String password = insertPassword.getText().toString();
    String confirm = insertFinal.getText().toString();

    //Validation for the fields
    // check if any of the fields are vaccant
    if (username.equals("") || password.equals("") || confirm.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    // check if both password matches
    if (!password.equals(confirm)) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    } else {
        // Save the Data in Database


       Intent intent1=new Intent(Register.this,LoginDBAdapter.class);
            Bundle userdata=new Bundle();
            userdata.putString("username",username);
            userdata.putString("name",name);
            userdata.putString("password",password);
            userdata.putString("confirm",confirm );
            intent1.putExtras(userdata);
            startActivity(intent1);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

**LoginDBAdapter.java**

```
public class LoginDBAdapter extends Activity {

TextView text;
 SQLiteDatabase mydb;
 String username,name,password;
    private static String DBNAME = "login.db";    // THIS IS THE SQLITE DATABASE FILE NAME.
    private static String TABLE = "Users";  
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    Bundle userdetails=getIntent().getExtras();
   username= userdetails.getString("username");
    name=userdetails.getString("name");
    password=userdetails.getString("password");
     text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txthead);


    createTable();  
    insertIntoTable(username,name,password);
}
public void createTable(){
    try
    {
    mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Username TEXT,Name TEXT, Password TEXT);");
    mydb.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in creating table", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public void onsearchclick(View view)
{


   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "subval of"+ subval+""+subval1+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    showTableValues();



}

public void insertIntoTable(String username,String name,String password){
    try{
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE + "(Username,Name,Password) VALUES('"+username+"','"+name+"','"+password+"')");

       mydb.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+e.toString()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     //System.out.println(""+e.toString()+"");
    }
}
```

The showTableValues will show the last entered username and password and name of the person

```
public void showTableValues()
{
    try
    {
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);

        Cursor cursor=mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Users", null);      
        int x = cursor.getCount(); //this will return number of records in current cursor
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+x+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if ( x == 0 )
        {
            //No rows are inserted in table
        } 
        else 
        {

            try 
            {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                 do {
                     String username=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Username")).toString();
                     String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")).toString();
                     String password=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Password")).toString();



                    String tempString="User Name:  "+username.toString();
                    String tempString1="Name: "+""+name.toString();
                     String tempString2="Password: "+""+password.toString();

                     TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txthead);
               text.setText(tempString);
                    text.append(tempString1);
                    text.append(tempString2);

                   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                finally 
                {
                cursor.close();
                mydb.close();
                }

                // }
            }
       }
    catch( Exception e)
            {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**fragment_register.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/insertFinal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/final1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/final1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Confirm Password" >


</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/insertUsername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter user name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtusername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/insertUsername"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/insertUsername"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="User Name:" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="125dp"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:text="Register" 
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/final1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Register"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
    android:text="Confirm password" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/insertFinal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:text="Password" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/insertPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Password"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Password"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="enter password" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/insertName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/insertPassword"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Name:" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtusername"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/insertName"
    android:text="Name:" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_register.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="show"
        android:onClick="onsearchclick" ></Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txthead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/show"    />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**in Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.login"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.login.LoginDBAdapter" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```